# Populating options using "ng-options" in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, javascript-objects

I have a dropdown and I need to populate it with the prices using AngularJS.  Unfortunately the structure of the JSON returned is not straight forward and I am unable to change it as it belongs to a legacy system.

Here is a sample of the JSON:

```
[
    {"name" : "simpleObjectName", "price" : "27.00"},
    {"name" : "simpleObjectName2", "price" : ["26.99", "27.00", "28.00"]},
    {"name" : "complexObjectName1", "availability" : { "price" : ["25.59", "26.40", "27.50"], "availability" : "AVAILABLE"}},
    {"name" : "complexObjectName2", "availability" : { "price" : ["42.99", "22.00", "237.00"], "availability" : "UNAVAILABLE"}},
    {"name" : "complexObjectName3", "availability" : { "price" : ["23.99", "216.00", "21.00"], "availability" : "UNAVAILABLE"}},
    {"name" : "complexObjectName4", "availability" : { "price" : "21.00", "availability" : "AVAILABLE"}}
]
```

I need to show the prices of the simpleObjects below in this dropdown together with the prices of the complexObjects only if availability is set to AVAILABLE.

I am new to angular and do not know whether there is a way to show the prices when you have such a structure.  Is there something that I can use?  I gave filters a try but started getting a couple of errors and had to revert the change.

**EDIT**:  Update to JSON.  Found out there can be multiple prices related to offers and color differences.  I need to show all the prices for all available complexObjects and simpleObjects.

Comment: you need to filter the array ...what have you tried? Can do it with a custom filter or map it in service or controller

Comment: @charlietfl i was trying to use something of this sort:
| filter:{ availability.availability : 'AVAILABLE' }  but im trying it now and it just returns me the complexObjects so that won't do the trick either..

Comment: I added a filter to SVK's answer but it hasn't been accepted yet.

Comment: @skubski I am not seeing your update here :/

Comment: This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed. I didn't want to post almost exactly the same answer with the addition of a filter...

Comment: @skubski sorry - not seeing the update.  So it will be visible once it's been peer reviewied or it should be visible on my end right now?

Comment: Nah, it got rejected for no reason so I answered myself.

Comment: @user1809790 did my solution never solve your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display the objects in the ng-repeat as follows:

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="c as (c.name + ' - ' + c.price + c.availability.price) for c in containers">
        <option value="">--select --</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And filter out the items that are unavailable in your controller:

```
$scope.containers = [yourcontainerjson].filter(function ($c) {
        if ($c.availability === undefined || 
            $c.availability.availability == 'AVAILABLE') {
            return $c;
        }
 });
```

You could also define a filter module and apply that in the ng-repeat. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wMF1nt7wXTzrX5BCLiSN?p=preview).

Comment: I figured out that a particular object can have 1 or several prices depending on some specs & offers.  Can these be shown?

Comment: Sure, they can be shown. But your JSON (data) seems to get a tad inconsistent. You might want to consider to alter the structure of your JSON when it gets fetched from your server. (Since it is a legacy system). I changed the updated data in the plunker and it still works.

Comment: then I believe I need to alter the structure indeed, as we would need that each price is a different option, so if a particular object has 3 prices, those would show up as 3 options in the list

Comment: You can overcome that hurdle easily. I updated my `plunker` to reflect [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/wMF1nt7wXTzrX5BCLiSN?p=preview) @user1809790.

Comment: @user1809790 did you see the updated version that alters your array of types?

Answer (score 0):

Updated [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/6V66F/156/)

HTML code:

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <h3>Option 1 (standard)</h3>

    <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="c as (c.name + ' - ' + c.price + c.availability.price) for c in containers">
        <option value="">--select --</option>
    </select>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` with `ng-if`

see this [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/PZrT1ftIjJzdei9U7Nch?p=preview)

**MarkUp**

```
<select>
  <option ng-repeat-start="r in records" ng-if="r.price">{{r.name}}-{{r.price}}</option>
  <option ng-repeat-end ng-if="!r.price && r.availability && r.availability.availability == 'AVAILABLE'">{{r.name}}-{{r.availability.price}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I figured out that a particular object can have 1 or several prices depending on some specs & offers.  Can these be shown?

Comment: Yes, you can edit `ng-if` condition based on your requirement.

Comment: sorry I am new to Angular and not sure how I can do a repeat inside an ng-if :/

Comment: I already added `ng-if`, you just have to change condition as you required. check `ng-if` in inside option tag.

Comment: yes but how am I going to loop to show the prices in the array as different options?  is there some index I can use?

Comment: @user1809790 Check [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PZrT1ftIjJzdei9U7Nch?p=preview) now I updated.